# Replace a word stored in a variable

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=''
replace="XXX"
for line in `cat test.csv`;do
name=`echo $line|cut -d"|" -f1`
      date=`echo $line|cut -d"|" -f3`
      echo $name
      echo $date
      sed -n "s/$name/XXX/gpw" output' test.csv
done
```

I need to replace value of `$name` by `XXX` but it's not working.

CSV file contains:

```
38880|update|20121227|customerXXXX|CXXX|Credit|Comp any|channel:XXX|XXX|XXX|0|Active|N|N|2012-12-31 17:37:46|Y|2012-12-31 17:37:46
```

And error is:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unterminated `s' command
```

Comment: @AshishTripurwar Surely that's not a verbatim copy of the script, since there's an unmatched `'` in there. Any other copy-paste errors? (Also, there are some other minor issues; run it through http://www.shellcheck.net .)

Comment: You should really indicate what is your desired output.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are doing too many things just to change the first column.

This should make:

```
awk -v subs="XXX" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {$1=subs}1' file
```

For your given input it returns:

```
XXX|update|20121227|customerXXXX|CXXX|Credit|Comp any|channel:XXX|XXX|XXX|0|Active|N|N|2012-12-31 17:37:46|Y|2012-12-31 17:37:46
```

To update your file, use:

```
awk -v subs="XXX" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {$1=subs}1' file > new_file && mv new_file file
```

If you needed to use bash, you can make use of `IFS` and `read` like this:

```
while IFS="|" read -r name _ date _
do
   echo $name
   echo $date
   sed -i.bak "s/$name/XXX/g" another_file #do the replacement
done < file
```

Note `$name` gets the value of the first field and `$date` the value of the third, based on `|` as delimiter.

Comment: thanks it's totally working with awk but i need pass column name from instead of $3 can you please suggest

Comment: What do you mean? Do you need to indicate the column number? Also, you'd better update your question so it is clear to everybody what you want.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can simplify things greatly by using `while` instead of `for`. You also don't need the `sed`. Bash, and other shells, have some quite extensive [string manipulation abilities](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html). So, a working version of your script could be:

```
$ while IFS='|' read -r name rest; do 
    printf "XXX|%s\n" "$rest"
 done < test.csv > new.csv
XXX|update|20121227|customerXXXX|CXXX|Credit|Comp any|channel:XXX|XXX|XXX|0|Active|N|N|2012-12-31 17:37:46|Y|2012-12-31 17:37:46
```

That will write the new lines into the `new.csv` file. If you also want to echo the values of `$name` and `$date` to the terminal but only save the changed file, use this instead:

```
$ > new.csv; while IFS='|' read -r name f2 date rest; do 
    printf "%s\n%s\n" "$date" "$name" 
    printf "XXX|%s|%s|%s\n" "$f2" "$date" "$rest" >> new.csv
 done < test.csv
```

You seem to want to do more manipulations as well. If so, you can read each field into a variable:

```
while IFS='|' read -r f{1..10}; do ... ;done; done < test.csv
```

The fields will be available as `$f1` through `$f15`. Alternatively, you could use arrays:

```
$ while IFS='|' read -r -a fields; do 
    for((i=0; i<${#fields[@]}; i++)); do 
        echo "Field $i : ${fields[$i]}" 
    done 
done < test.csv 
Field 0 : 38880
Field 1 : update
Field 2 : 20121227
Field 3 : customerXXXX
Field 4 : CXXX
Field 5 : Credit
Field 6 : Comp any
Field 7 : channel:XXX
Field 8 : XXX
Field 9 : XXX
Field 10 : 0
Field 11 : Active
Field 12 : N
Field 13 : N
Field 14 : 2012-12-31 17:37:46
Field 15 : Y
Field 16 : 2012-12-31 17:37:46
```

Comment: it's working but i need to replace permanently in file can you please Advise

Comment: @AshishTripurwar in what file? If you use my suggestions, you could read an input file and then redirect the output to an output file. See updated answer.

Comment: As the OP just wants to use first and third column, I would suggest doing `while read -r name _ date _` instead.

Comment: no second one is not working at all yeah i have redirected the output but it print only modified column

Comment: @AshishTripurwar I added another approach that prints the name and date to the terminal and then changes the lines and saves them in a new file.

Comment: @fedorqui since the OP wasn't actually doing anything with the date but echoing I had assumed it was only there for debugging. No reason to assume that though, so answer edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 'h;s/^\([^|]*\)|[^|]*|\([^|]*\)|.*/\1\
\2/p
g
:a
s/^\([^|]*\)\(|.*\)\1/\1\2XXX/
t a
s/^\([^|]*\)|/XXX|/' test.csv
```

try this.

1. extract and print name + date
2. recursively replace name in line
3. replace first occurence of name